# Winforms TextBox margin? space difference

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have observed that the margin setting for the TextBox has no apparent affect (even though I wish it did) on the control. However, I wrote a simple test program using a TextBox and it has a different margin! I have carefully compared my two programs and there is no relevant difference between them but one has only two pixels from the edge to the first character entered in the TextBox and the other has seven pixels to an identical character! Is there an explanation for this discrepancy?

The designer settings for the TextBox are identical in both programs:

```
this.textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
this.textBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
this.textBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.textBox1.HideSelection = false;
this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.textBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.textBox1.MaxLength = 0;
this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
this.txtBody.TabIndex = 0;
this.textBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both;
```

There are no other settings for either TextBox except "Name", "Size", and event handlers.

Example screenshot: [image: Example]

Comment: Other than the glyph overhang needed for the first character, and you compared different glyphs, no.  TextBox knows beans about Padding.  And Margin affects spacing between controls, not the text inside it.

Comment: It was an identical character... :-) Question edited to specify.

Comment: How is this supposed to give us a repro?  You need at least two snippets.  A screenshot wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: As I said the designer settings are literally identical. Are you suggesting I attempt to include the entire content of both programs? There is nothing in the screenshots other than what I described but I will learn how to include one.

Comment: @Hans Thank you for the feedback. I am new to asking questions. I will get better.

Comment: @Hans Your questions and prompting have paid off. Further and closer examination has revealed that the program environments were defaulting to different fonts. When I specified the font they were the same. Thank you for helping me find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hans Your questions and prompting have paid off. Further and closer examination has revealed that the program environments were defaulting to different fonts. When I specified the font the margins were the same. Thank you for helping me find the answer.